# Instagram sharing Photos/Videos

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I am developing app for Instagram analytics and I want to have funcionality to share photos or videos from mobile phone. Is there any API for posting pictures and videos?

If there is not, I know there is intent for sharing, but how to handle if the user has multiple accounts on his phone? Is there a chooser for the account or how is it done?

Im developing it mainly for Android, so, it would be good to know how to do this from android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not possible to post image in Instagram like facebook or twitter.

use below code to share with intent

```
        btnShareIMG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
            if (intent != null)
            {
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
                try {
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imagePath, "Nilesh", "Rathod")));
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e("ERROR",e.printStackTrace());
                }
                shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                startActivity(shareIntent);
            }
            else
            {                   
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id="+"com.instagram.android"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Alright, any idea how to change account inside instagram application when sharing?

Comment: @MiljanVulovic no idea about it

Comment: most welcom@MiljanVulovic

Comment: what about Videos?

Comment: @AkashDubey  sorry to say no idea about video right now my friend

Comment: https://instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/ using intent from this, I am able to share video but first it asks for 'Story' or 'Instagram' and when I choose story then nothing happens!!
Can u please help me with this like when sharing image same scenario occurs?

Comment: @AkashDubey i will try n let u know about this